# Why to decrement the Length of date string twice after sending data in 16 bit DFF (Data Frame Format)?

Tags: spi, embedded

My instructor told use that we have to decrement the length data string SPI twice after sending the data.
[image]

The image will show the code.
The board I am using to run the code is STM32F407 DISCOVERY BOARD.

I don't get why do we have to decrement twice?

The DR (Data Register) of the SPI is of 16 bits anyways, so cannot we just send the data in one decrement like in the 8 bit data frame format?

Also, the "length" variable is of the type uint32_t.

So, why cannot we just send the data without decrementing the length twice?

Please help me out with this..

Thanks!

~Aditya.U

Comment: You are asking us to tell you why your teacher is telling you something you don't understand? Wouldn't it be easier to just ask the source? Is there some reason you can't?

Comment: I have bought a course on udemy and the instructor doesn't seem to answer the question. I have given them a bad rating but still they don't seem to care. 
If you know the answer, please let me know. I am stuck on this concept.

Comment: Apparently, `length` represents the number of 8-bit elements in the buffer.  And a 16-bit SPI transfer transfers two 8-bit elements from the buffer.  Therefore decrement `length` twice after a 16-bit SPI transfer.

Comment: @kkrambo, so my if there are two chars in the TxBuffer, {A,B}; so, in the 8 bit DFF, first 'A' will be sent and then 'B' will be sent. so length has to be decremented once. But in the 16 bit DFF, both 'A' and 'B' will be sent (because TxBuffer is typecasted to uint16_t) and length has to be decremented twice. Is this right?

Comment: @AdityaUbarhande Yes, I think you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

No, because if you send two bytes, or 16 bits, in one SPI data register write, you need to then point forward two bytes, or one word of 16 bit. If you send 16 bits and point to next byte then you will send each byte twice.

Comment: So, do you mean that because the TxBuffer is of 8 bits, and you are sending a 16 bit data to the DR, you have to decrement twice? so, something like this: TxBuffer = {A, B}; But the DR = (uint16_t*)TxBuffer. So the DR will get 'A' and 'B' at once and nothing will be left in the TxBuffer. Hence, we have to decrement the length twice? Is it like that? Please let me know...